# Python Floats/Sum functions

Tags: python

a. Read the file and report the grade for each student. The grade is the sum of the grades for each question. The columns are tab-separated. You will need to use the float() function to convert a string into a float. You can also use the sum() function, which takes as input a list and returns the sum of its elements.

ORIGINAL FILE:

```
%%file midterm-grades.txt
1.1 1.2 1.3 1.4 1.5 2.1 2.2 2.3 3.1 3.2 3.3 3.4 3.5 3.6 4.1 4.2 4.3 4.4 4.5 4.6 4.7 4.8 5.1 5.2 5.3 5.4a    5.4b    5.5 5.6
===========================================================================================================================
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   4   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
===========================================================================================================================
0   0.5 0.5 1   1   3   2   3   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   1.5 2   0   1.5 1.5 1.5
0   0.5 1   1   1   3   3   4.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 0   0   0   0   0   0   0   0   2   2   1.5 1.5 2   2   2
0   0.7 0.5 1   1   3   0   0   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 2   2   2   2   1   2   2
1   0.5 0.8 1   1   3   0   0   1.5 1.5 1.3 1.5 1.5 0.7 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0   1.5 1.5 1.5 2   1.5 2   0   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 2   2   1
1   0.7 0.5 0   0   2.5 0   0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0   0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 0.5 0   0.5 0.5 2   2   2   0   0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   3   0   0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 2   2   2   0   2   1.5 0
1   0.7 0.8 1   1   3   3   3   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 0   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   4   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 0   1   0
1   1   1   1   1   2.5 3   4   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0   1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   2   3   4.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 2   2   2   2
1   0.5 1   1   1   3   2.5 4   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 2   2   2
1   0.7 0.8 1   1   1.5 3   5   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   2   1.5 1   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   3   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 0   1   0   0
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   5   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
1   0.7 0.5 1   1   1.5 1   0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 2   0   0   0
1   0.7 0.8 1   1   0   1   0.5 0   1.5 1   1.5 0   0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0   0.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 0   0   0   0
1   0.7 0.8 1   1   1.5 0   0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 2   2   2   0   2   2   2
1   0.7 0.8 0.5 1   3   3   4   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   2   0   2   2   1.5
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   5   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   5   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   5   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   2   2   1   1   2
1   1   1   1   1   3   2   3   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   2   2   1.5 0   2   0   2
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   5   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.3 1.5 2   2   2   2   2   1   2
1   1   1   0.5 0.5 2.5 0   0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.3 0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 0   1   2   0
1   1   1   1   1   3   0   0   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 0   2   2   0
1   0.5 0.8 1   1   3   0   0   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1   1.5 2   2   2   0   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   5   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1   1.5 2   2   2   0   1   2   2
1   0.7 1   1   1   3   2   4   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 0.5 1.5 2   2   2   0   2   2   2
1   0.5 1   1   1   3   2   3   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 1   2   2   2
1   0.7 1   1   1   2.5 3   3   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 0.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 0   2   2   1.5
1   0.7 0.8 1   1   3   2   2   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1   0   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   4   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 2   2   2
1   0.5 0.3 1   1   1.5 3   3.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 0   1   1   1
1   0.8 1   0   0   0   0   0   1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 0   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 2   2   1.5
1   0.5 0.8 1   1   3   1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 0.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
1   0.3 0.8 1   1   1.5 3   3   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1   1.5 1   1.5 2   2   1.5 1.5 2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   3   2   2   1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 1.5 2   2   2   2   2   2   2
```

And this is my code:

```
# Read file
midterm = open("midterm-grades.txt", "r")
# Report grade for each student
midterm_content = midterm.read()
indiv = midterm_content.split("\n")
# Get rid of Headers
students = indiv[4:]
for i in students : 
    withouttabs = i.split("\t")
    print "Student grade is ", sum(float(withouttabs))
```

Cannot figure out how to float the grade so I can do the sum function, or pretty much completely lost at this point.

Comment: Presumably you're getting `TypeError: float() argument must be a string or a number`, in which case the [mcve] you should have posted is `float([])` - you need to convert each number in the list *separately*.

Comment: Can you provide some lines of your file?

Comment: Hi Jon, thanks for getting back to me! In the original dataset, there are a lot of numbers—is there a quicker way to do this?

Comment: @Kasramvd we are not given student names; we just got a bunch of lines, and each line represents a "student." The error I get is `TypeError: 'float' object is not callable`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, you cannot float() on a list of strings.  Simply iterate over the list of individual strings, and float() them one at a time, as shown below:

```
midterm = open("midterm-grades.txt", "r")
# Report grade for each student
midterm_content = midterm.read()
indiv = midterm_content.split("\n")
# Get rid of Headers
students = indiv[4:]
for i in students : 
    withouttabs = i.split("\t")
    total = 0   ## initialize total for each student
    for j in withouttabs:   ## now, iterate over each list of strings
        total = total + float(j)
    print "Student grade is ", total   ## finally, print the total
```

Comment: Thanks, I'm still getting the hang of this.  Is this better?

Comment: Definite improvement, thank you

Comment: Thank you both so much! I am still trying to understand all the Python terminology so apologies for any confusion on my part.